# MongoDB Indexes from development to production

Tags: .net, mongodb, indexing

I'am a newbie with mongoDB. Now I'am developing a personal project. I'm using MongoVUE, and while I'm developing I create my indexes with MongoVUE. But of course the DB im working on is for development.  How I copy my indexes, to the production DB? When I pass to production the collections will be empty, how I create those indexes with empty collections?

Script? program to do this? what you recommend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an index with [MongoVUE](http://www.mongovue.com/) it'll show you the actual MongoDB shell command in the **Learn Shell** panel at the bottom.  Just keep a record of these commands and run them directly through the shell on your production server when you're ready to deploy.

Answer (score 1):

If you base your setup only on click-tools then you also have to click in production!

There should be code in some language for the bootstrap of a new database with all necessary definitions of indexes, schemas or whatever. This true for every project and every database. I would consider other approaches as running productions in kindergarten-style by people that don't know better. Don't take it personally but we have seen so much similar-style weak deployments without a strategy moving from development to testing to production.